# Inner matrix dimensions must agree (for GMM)

Tags: matlab, matrix

I know that this question is very common, and I tried to figure out where the problem comes from, but I am not able to see it. I am trying to estimate a GMM function, and I got this error "Inner matrix dimensions must agree.". I got the error in line 48(q=g*R').
Please, if someone could help me I would really appreciate that. Thank you advance.

```
    function [q] = Q(param,M,intr,cond)

   T = length(intr);

  % Population moments
  % [PMvec] = populat0ion_moments(param);
   %sigma = param(2);  
   alpha = param(1);
   beta = param(2);
   sigma = param(3);
   b = param(4);


   intert = intr(1:end-2,1);
   intertw = intr(2:end-1,1);

    a = zeros(1, T-2);
    c = zeros(1, T-2);
    d = zeros(1, T-2);
    e = zeros(1, T-2);

   for i=1:T-2

         a(:,i)=(intertw(i) - intert(i) - alpha - beta.*intertw(i));
         c(:,i) =(intertw(i) - intert(i) - alpha - beta.*intertw(i)).*intert(i);         
         d(:,i) =(intertw(i) - intert(i) - alpha - beta.*intertw(i)).^2 + (sigma^2).*(intert(i)).^(2*b);
         e(:,i) =((intertw(i) - intert(i) - alpha - beta.*intertw(i)).^2 + (sigma^2).*(intert(i)).^(2*b))*intert(i);
   end

   g(1,1)=1/(T-2.*1).*sum(a);

   g(1,2)=1/(T-2.*1).*sum(c);

   g(1,3)=1/(T-2.*1).*sum(d);

   g(1,4)=1/(T-2.*1).*sum(e);

  g;  

  % Sample moments and orthogonality conditions 

  % GMM matrix 
  % we are using diff algorithm for optimizing. we start using the seecond
  % one.
  %I.- Using 'lsqnonlin' function %the cholesky function multiplies the
%   %first part of the gmm estimator and we get very similar things
   R=chol(inv(M));
    q=g*R';
%      
%   II.- Using 'fminsearch' function
%q=g(cond)*inv(M)*g(cond)'; %GMM estimate (simplex method)

%SE_mu = sqrt(1/T * R(1,1));
```

Comment: This is really a job for the debugger. What are the dimensions of `g`? What are the dimensions of `R`? Are they what you expect them to be?

Comment: what you give for M?

Comment: It is the identity matrix, that it is indirectly specified in the GMM estimation. I have my doubts that there is the problem, as I already used this code to estimate other parameters with other specifications for the orthogonality condition and it worked. I will review again.

Comment: I think that I found where the problem was. In the GMM function, I forgot to uncoment a command which was going to be used for the M matrix. Thank you a lot!